Alternative way to compute degree of Frobenius endomorphism
Let $p$ be a prime, $q=p^r$, $K=\mathbb{F}_{q}$, $E/K$ an elliptic curve and let $\phi$ be the $q^{th}$ Frobenius endormorphism i.e. $\phi=(x^q,y^q,1)$. I want to show that $\phi$ has degree $q$. I am able to show it using the definition of degree of a map i.e.
$$\deg\phi=[K(E):\phi^*K(E)]$$
However I want to find a different proof, more linked to elliptic curves in particular since this can be used for any algebraic curve. Maybe linked to isogenies. Can someone help me?

Do you mean you'd like to use the fact that $\hat{\phi} \circ \phi = [\deg(\phi)]$? You might be able to prove it this way, but the nature of $\hat{\phi}$ will depend on whether $E$ is ordinary or supersingular.
